# helm-grep-do-git-grep searches in the current directory

Tags: emacs, git-grep, emacs-helm

> helm-grep-do-git-grep with a prefix arg grep whole repo and without
>   grep only current dir.

I want it reversed

> helm-grep-do-git-grep without a prefix arg grep whole repo and with
>   grep only current dir.

How can i define a function to reverse it or define keyboard shortcut ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a general solution for any command where you want to reverse the meaning of the prefix argument (at least for commands that interpret their prefix args as booleans).

```
(defun foo (&optional arg)
  "Do something.  Do something else with prefix ARG."
  (interactive "P")
  (if arg
      (message "something else")
    (message "something")))

(defun anti-foo (&optional arg)
  "Like `foo', but with opposite behavior w.r.t. ARG."
  (interactive "P")
  (if arg
      (foo nil)
    (foo '(4))))
```

---

If you just want to replace the function (may or may not be OK, see below), you can use advice:

```
(advice-add 'foo
            :around
            (lambda (orig &rest args)
              "Reverse sense of prefix arg."
              (let ((arg (car args)))
                (if arg
                    (setq args (cons nil (cdr args)))
                  (setq args (cons '(4) (cdr args))))
                (apply orig args))))
```

If the function is only an end user function, it's probably OK to use advice on it (skimming the helm source, `helm-grep-do-git-grep` is probably OK to advise).  If the function is used by other functions, advice may cause the dependent functions to misbehave (because you're effectively changing the advised function's definition).

---

Aside: If you're not familiar with Emacs's prefix arguments, `nil` is used for no prefix, `'(4)` is used for a single prefix, `'(16)` is used for a double prefix, and so on.

Comment: Is it possible to make the result window be the minibuffer and not a different window?

Comment: @Adel I have no idea.  You should make a new post for that question.